# How to get missing Computernames in a Active Directory OU

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory

I would like to get missing computer hostnames in our Active Directory.

Currently we have a naming convention for notebooks:

```
NB-DE-00001
```

and for PC's:

```
PC-DE-00001
```

Currently, however, some hostnames have not been incremented, but a higher number has simply been chosen manually.

In AD, for example

```
NB-DN-00001
NB-DE-00004
```

Now I would like to determine the missing ones so 2-3 in this example.

Is there a PowerShell way to do this?

Comment: Yes, of course, please update your question with what you are currently trying and what is going wrong :-)

Comment: If idea is what u want, u can 1.) Get all the computer Names. 2.) generate in a loop the ideal computer names 3.) In the same loop, check if a computer with that name exists and print out the ones that doesn't have a match.

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be a number of ways to do this. But this is a decent starting point to list all of the missing numbers in five-digit format.

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*-*'" -SearchBase 'OU Path' |
    Where Name -match '-\d+$' | Select-Object -Expand Name
[int[]]$UsedNumbers = $Computers -replace '.*?-(?=\d+$)' | Sort-Object { [int]$_ }
1..$UsedNumbers[-1] | Where {$_ -notin $UsedNumbers} |
    Foreach-Object { "{0:d5}" -f $_ }
```

You have not specified if `NB-DE-*`, `NB-DN-*`, or `PC-DE-*` use the same pool of numbers, if those systems share the same OUs, or if `PC-DE-00001` can coexist with `NB-DN-00001`.

Comment: Thanks for that! Actually it looks pretty impressive to me, because I'm not familar with powershell but anyway.. Learning by doing..

As far as I can see at the result there are not only empty. In the $Computer array are some active computers which should be not

Edit:
Could you explain the [int[]] part a bit?

Comment: `[int[]]` casts the result into an array of integers. It turns `00001` into `1` and helps with sorting. Later I check a loop of values 1 through your maximum number to see if they have been used. Once comparisons are made, I convert the numbers back into the 5 digit padded format.

Comment: Sometimes it is hard to make a computer filter when posters withhold critical information. A lot of times people will say, "I use this computer naming scheme" and only list a couple of examples. There could actually be ten different naming templates. So I just try to be more generic about it and let you fix it to meet your needs. If you want it to be more exact, that can be done. Here `$computers` is going to be any computer name that ends with `-number`.

Comment: The solution assumes that 00001 can only be used once in an OU regardless of the naming convention. If that is not a correct assumption, then it needs to be tweaked further. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a really dirty workaround but it works.. For me as a beginner it's okay but I would like to improve my skills so I would appreciate it when you guys could give me some tips.

My solution right now:

My first step is to get a sorted list of computers and notebooks (I just need theese filters for stuff)

```
$ADnbSorted = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=computers,dc=example,dc=com' -Filter {(Name -like "NB-DE-*") -and (Name -notlike "NB-DE-M*") }| Sort-Object | Select-Object Name

$ADpcSorted = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=computers,dc=example,dc=com' -Filter {(Name -notlike "PC-DE-R*") -and (Name -like "PC-DE-*") } | Sort-Object | Select-Object Name
```

My next step is that I create a template list how a correct list of hostnames should look like

```
$templatehostname = 1..$ADpcSorted[-1].Name |
         ForEach-Object{ "$prefix" + $_.ToString("00000")}
```

I use prefix because its an little application where the user can enter if he wants to know all PC's Unkown and all Notebook Unkown Hostnames :)

After that I just compare both of theese and add the missing entrys just to a new list

```
> ForEach($Hostname in $templatehostname) 
>     {
>         if (-Not ($ADpcSorted.Name.Contains($Hostname))) 
>     {  
>     $freeHostname += $Hostname 
>      }
>      }
```

I'm sorry for that bunch of shit :)